# Error : Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, mobile-automation

Team,

Trying to install lib which is pre-requisite to run my automation code, observe below error :

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13]
>   Permission denied:
>   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/futures-3.2.0.dist-info'

**My environment :**

- MAC : 10.14

Comment: Either use sudo or a virtual environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either go with creating a Python virtual environment as suggested by Ernie.

Or you can use pip install's `--user` option to install packages into your home directory where   you have all required permissions. E.g.:

```
pip install myPackage --user
```

Do not forget to add the install directory in your home to PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
source anaconda3/bin/activate
```

and then run

```
 pip3 install <package-name>
```

Worked for me.